# SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault в простом примере pjsip на python

Tags: python, swig, pjsip

```
Thread 11 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7f6fff885640 (LWP 147247)]
0x00007f701420f0ae in PyType_GenericAlloc () from /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007f701420f0ae in PyType_GenericAlloc () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#1  0x00007f7013384331 in SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance (swig_this=0x7f7013748570, data=0x5573a205ded0) at pjsua2_wrap.cpp:2288
#2  SWIG_Python_NewPointerObj(void*, swig_type_info*, int, PyObject*) (ptr=<optimized out>, type=<optimized out>, flags=flags@entry=0, self=0x0) at pjsua2_wrap.cpp:2395
#3  0x00007f70133b44dc in SwigDirector_Account::onRegState(pj::OnRegStateParam&) (this=0x5573a217dfe0, prm=<optimized out>) at pjsua2_wrap.cpp:8779
#4  0x00007f70132086ba in pj::Endpoint::on_reg_state2(int, pjsua_reg_info*) (acc_id=<optimized out>, info=0x7f6fff883d30) at ../src/pjsua2/endpoint.cpp:801
#5  0x00007f7012f300d1 in regc_cb () at ../lib/libpjsua.so.2
#6  0x00007f70137a0f37 in regc_tsx_callback () at ../lib/libpjsip-ua.so.2
#7  0x00007f7012ed9bac in tsx_set_state () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#8  0x00007f7012edacf4 in tsx_on_state_proceeding_uac () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#9  0x00007f7012edb3f5 in tsx_on_state_calling () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#10 0x00007f7012edd6be in pjsip_tsx_recv_msg () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#11 0x00007f7012edd7c5 in mod_tsx_layer_on_rx_response () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#12 0x00007f7012ec44e7 in pjsip_endpt_process_rx_data () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#13 0x00007f7012ec46a6 in endpt_on_rx_msg () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#14 0x00007f7012ecb2b4 in pjsip_tpmgr_receive_packet () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#15 0x00007f7012ecefaf in udp_on_read_complete () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#16 0x00007f7012d9662f in ioqueue_dispatch_read_event () at ../lib/libpj.so.2
#17 0x00007f7012d9807f in pj_ioqueue_poll () at ../lib/libpj.so.2
#18 0x00007f7012ec4166 in pjsip_endpt_handle_events2 () at ../lib/libpjsip.so.2
#19 0x00007f7012f3ea05 in pjsua_handle_events () at ../lib/libpjsua.so.2
#20 0x00007f7012f3ea4a in worker_thread () at ../lib/libpjsua.so.2
#21 0x00007f7012d9964a in thread_main () at ../lib/libpj.so.2
#22 0x00007f7013f09259 in start_thread () at /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#23 0x00007f70140265e3 in clone () at /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Код работает до момента успешной авторизации

```
12:17:24.693            pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP outbound status for acc 0 is not active
12:17:24.693            pjsua_acc.c  ....sip:894377@sip2.eri.su: registration success, status=200 (OK), will re-register in 299 seconds
12:17:24.693            pjsua_acc.c  ....Keep-alive timer started for acc 0, destination:45.139.24.57:8160, interval:15s
```

и потом грохается. Сам код

```
import pjsua2 as pj
import time

class Account(pj.Account):
    def onRegState(self, prm):
        print(prm)

    def onIncomingCall(self, prm):
        c = pj.Call(self, call_id=prm.callId)
        call_prm = pj.CallOpParam()
        call_prm.statusCode = 180
        c.answer(call_prm)
        
        ci = c.getInfo()
        print(ci)

        call_prm.statusCode = 200
        c.answer(call_prm)

def main():
    ep_cfg = pj.EpConfig()
    ep = pj.Endpoint()
    ep.libCreate()
    ep.libInit(ep_cfg)
    sipTpConfig = pj.TransportConfig()
    sipTpConfig.port = 9060
    ep.transportCreate(pj.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, sipTpConfig)
    ep.libStart()

    acfg = pj.AccountConfig()
    acfg.idUri = "sip:894377@sip2.eri.su"
    acfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:sip2.eri.su:8160"
    cred = pj.AuthCredInfo("digest", "*", "894377", 0, "Tc3YjU2MTkxN")
    acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.append( cred )
    # Create the account
    acc = Account()
    acc.create(acfg)
    time.sleep(60)

    # Destroy the library
    ep.libDestroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Получилось ли победить проблему?